# Handling timestamps in juniper rust

Tags: rust, graphql

any idea how to support timestamps in graphql with juniper?

I'd like to be able to get timestamps from a query/mutation as store them as is in mongodb.

I've been trying to create a custom scalar but haven't succeeded so far.

thank you for your help.

Comment: looks like i32 is the way to go check https://github.com/briandeboer/counter-service/blob/41e833d32d03fb8a7403a6b8386e27f9f73b8af6/src/models/bucket.rs#L138

Comment: Thank you @ozkanpakdil i32 max is like year 2038
Could be fine for my needs now but for not a solid long term solution.

Comment: you can use string too :) that will go forever, lets see if rust can stay that longer. check https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/rust-examples/tree/main/juniper

Comment: Super userful! Thank you. I went for f64 as Mongo supports u64. It makes it eaier for me to query using gt to compare 2 timestamps.
And I hope Rust will last forever. Ruby is still there so why not Rust? :D